# Why can't I select my Bluetooth speaker as audio output device after reconnecting?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluetooth-speaker

I have a new Bluetooth speaker, which I connect to and then select it as audio output device in Sound settings. However, if I suspend my laptop (or simply disable Bluetooth) and later reconnect, then it is no longer listed under the output devices. How can I debug this?

Possibly also relevant: I also cannot simply reconnect, but have to re-pair for the connection to work. This is also the first Bluetooth speaker this happens with.

(I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.)

Comment: Possibly relevant to people coming across this in the future: it's still quite dodgy, but I find that if, when I'm done using the Bluetooth speaker, I manually switch back to the regular audio output in the Sound settings, then explicitly disconnect the Bluetooth speaker, the next time it is more likely to reconnect. Not ideal, but better than nothing.